# SQL server backup job is skipping databases

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-backups

I am having issues with backup jobs. I have a job that runs and backup all the online databases (around 25 database ranges from 3 TB to 10 MB in size).

When these databases were in different servers, the FULL backups worked fine.
But after we consolidated the databases to one server, the backup job is skipping some database backups. No errors logged any where, but those databases don't exist in the destination folder.

The differentials backups are working fine but the monthly and weekly FULL backup jobs that is skipping some databases. It looks like there is a time out or some bottleneck that creates this situation.

I did sp_configure on one of the old servers and here are some configs that are different. could any of those cause this issue?

```
NEW SERVER:
name    minimum maximum config_value    run_value
Ad Hoc Distributed Queries  0   1   1   1
awe enabled 0   1   0   0
max server memory (MB)  16  2147483647  286720  286720
min server memory (MB)  0   2147483647  0   0

OLD SERVER:
Ad Hoc Distributed Queries  0   1   0   0
awe enabled 0   1   1   0
max server memory (MB)  16  2147483647  2147483647  2147483647
min server memory (MB)  0   2147483647  0   16
```

Regards,
RM

Comment: Are you using `sp_MSforeachdb`?

Comment: No. I am using a cursor to go through the databases. Sorry. I didn't know how to post it. so I created another stackoverflow entry - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19301754/sql-server-full-backup-job-is-skipping-databases.